# Error Logging in windows Phone8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, logging

- How can we log exceptions and error for windows Phone8.0 app
- I also want a mechanism to delete the logs after a period of time
- Is there a method other than ISO to log error

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write them to files in isolated storage. You can write code to iterate over the file system to clean them up. If this is just for testing use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to manually remove logs.

An alternative is to build a logging service and have your devices connect and write to it when they have a data connection.